# google ajax crawling rewrite

Tags: ajax, url-rewriting, hashbang

I have a site with some ajax content.
links to ajax content pages are as follows

## !/category/id/ident/name/

apache rewrite
 RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /somephp.php?cat_id=$1&ident=$2 [L]
redirects these links to /somephp.php?cat_id=id&ident=ident

I'm assuming google makes a request to /_escaped_fragment_?category/id/ident/name/

that is to say, no key=value pairs in new google request.
Then I assume I can rewrite this to /googlecontent.php?cat_id=id
so delivering googles html snapshot.
I've not been able to locate any information regarding _escaped_fragment_?whatever not having key=value pairs, is this ok with google?